# What would be angular ng-option equivalent of this select?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am struggling to get this into an ng-option. Is it even possible?

```
<select ng-model="detail_type_id">
   <optgroup ng-repeat="type in data.detailTypes" label="{{type.name}}">
      <option ng-repeat="t in type.children" value="{{t.id}}">{{t.name}}</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

DetailTypes looks like this:

```
[
 {"id":7, 
  "parent_id":null, 
  "name":"Contact", 
  "children":[
     {"id":8,
      "parent_id":7,
      "name":"Address",
      "children":[]
     },
     {"id":12,
      "parent_id":7,
      "name":"Something else",
      "children":[]
     }
   ]},
 {"id":16,
  "parent_id":null,
  "name":"Other",
  "children":[
     {"id":10,
      "parent_id":16,
      "name":"Remarks",
      "children":[]}
   ]
 }
]
```

Child id needs to be selected. Nesting cannot be deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ngOptions` directive does not work with multidimensional objects. So you need to flatten your array to use it.

I wrote a filter for that:

```
app.filter('flatten' , function(){
  return function(array){
    return array.reduce(function(flatten, group){
      group.children.forEach(function(child){
        child.groupName = group.name;
        flatten.push(child)
      })
      return flatten;
    },[]);
  }
})
```

And the HTML part would be like this:

```
<select ng-model="detail_type_id"
        ng-options="item.id as item.name 
                    group by item.groupName for item 
                    in data.detailTypes | flatten track by item.id">
</select>
```

***Plunker (version #1 with filter):***
https://plnkr.co/edit/dxi7j8oxInv2VRJ1aL7F

I also modified your object to be like this:

```
[{
  "id": 7,
  "parent_id": null,
  "name": "Contact",
  "children": [{
    "id": 8,
    "parent_id": 7,
    "name": "Address",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "id": 12,
    "parent_id": 7,
    "name": "Something else",
    "children": []
  }]
}, {
  "id": 16,
  "parent_id": null,
  "name": "Other",
  "children": [{
    "id": 10,
    "parent_id": 16,
    "name": "Remarks",
    "children": []
  }]
}]
```

**EDIT:**

After suggestion I wrote another version without the filter, but flattening the array inside the controller.

***Additional Controller JS:***

```
$scope.flattenDetailTypes = flattenDetailTypes($scope.data.detailTypes);

  function flattenDetailTypes(array){
    return array.reduce(function(flatten, group){
      group.children.forEach(function(child){
        child.groupName = group.name;
        flatten.push(child)
      })
      return flatten;
    },[]);
  }
```

***Markup:***

```
<select ng-model="detail_type_id"
        ng-options="item.id as item.name group by item.groupName for item in flattenDetailTypes track by item.id"></select>
```

***Plunker (version #2 without filter):***
https://plnkr.co/edit/D4APZ6

Comment: Object is little bit larger and translated, so there could be errors. The question is can you write <select ng-option="..."></select> to achieve same functionality?

Comment: Oh yeah.. I got it. I will make a try.

Comment: Nice solution, but as a improvement I'd suggest you to do it once in controller instead of doing a filter.

Comment: Thanks @developer033. I wrote your suggestion and edited my answer  with that.

Comment: Filter can be used in controller too, so it seems to be fine solution.